# What is the use of this syntax: <!---->?

Tags: html

I've been working with the design UI of our website and looking for some templates available in the web.

Then I encountered with this syntax `<!---->` and I'm not familiar with it.

Can you please tell me what is it and what is it used for?

thank you.

Comment: This is the html comment.

Comment: <!-- --> allows you to insert comments into an HTML document and have them completely ignored by the browser.

Comment: ok.. i guess that is why all the code below it is colored gray in my text editor. highly appreciated. thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other posts have mentioned the `<!---->` code in HTML is used for adding comments - a note left in the code by a developer with some info for other developers, or to remember something themselves. This code is viewable in the source but not displayed when viewing the HTML in the browser. Ex:

```
<!-- We need to update this each year -->
<div>&copy; 2009 - 2016</div>
```

will produce:

```
© 2009 - 2016
```

In most cases the comment can be removed with no side-effect on the code. It's simply a note for developers.

### Other Uses

**Commenting Out Code**
In addition to comments you'll sometimes see HTML code wrapped by `<!---->`. Ex:

```
<!-- Add this later
  <img src="article.jpg" alt="Article">
-->
```

The above code will remove the entire image tag from the browser view. This is useful if you want to temporarily remove some HTML from a page, for testing/debugging or for later use. You'll sometimes see entire HTML sections commented out.

**Conditional Code**
Another common use of comments is to add conditional code used by specific browsers. The following snippet of code would only be read by Internet Explorer 8, and would apply a black background color to the body.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

**Website Builders**
Some website builders generate their own code comments for internal use. For example, if you use [Squarespace](https://www.squarespace.com/) the generated code will contain comments like:

```
<!-- This is Squarespace. --><!-- www -->
```

These snippets, in some cases, are used by the generators themselves as a marker for inserting other code.

**Build Scripts**
There's a small chance the comment tag is being used as part of a build script, and in this case removing it would cause issues. Here's an example:

```
<!-- build:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

The above code, used with a build system like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and a Gulp plugin like [HTML Replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace) will replace the content between the `<!-- build:css-->` and `<!-- endbuild -->` tags with new code. Removing either one of those comment tags will cause errors.

Answer (score 2):

**html comment tag**

White space is not permitted between the markup declaration open delimiter(""). A common error is to include a string of hyphens ("---") within a comment. **Authors should avoid putting two or more adjacent hyphens inside comments.**

Reference : https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html

in that page goto 3.2.4 Comments title

Comment: you must add in your answer, the answer itself. that "it is a html comment tag". nevertheless upvoted because of the extra info.

Answer (score 1):

this is an html comment tag.See this link below to know more
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp

Answer (score 1):

This allows you commenting your html

```
 <!--- my comment -->
```

(with `-->` to close it that's right)